# Ruby on Rails: 4.2.0 differences between rails and bin/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So starting from Rails 4.1.x there seems to be a recommended way to use rails under the application folder. Instead of the traditional:

```
rails server
```

it is recommended by Rails official guide to use

```
bin/rails server
```

It looks like the bin/rails is referencing rails with additional stuff. What would be the additional benefits of using bin/rails compared to rails?

A second question is - I was used to use rails server, rails console, etc. rather than bin/rails server, bin/rails console. Without using bin/rails, would I lose anything (like misloading some libs, etc.)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following line in your bin/rails file: `puts "In the bin/rails file"`

Now run `rails server`. You'll likely see that the `rails` command is executing the `bin/rails` file.

I'm guessing the official guide suggests using `bin/rails` for two reasons:

1. Avoid using another instance of rails if your paths are not set up properly.
2. Speed - `bin/rails` seems to be a bit faster than just `rails`

Comment: excellent. But for the reason No.2, speed, it seems counter-intuitive. bin/rails is using all that in rails/command, but with extra settings. is there a reference for the performance reason?

Comment: I'm guessing the speed improvement (if there is any - there seemed to be a bit when I tested) comes from the OS not having to search for the executable.

Comment: Just `rails` uses whatever version of Rails you happen to have installed as a gem. Newer versions of that tool will auto-detect which type of application you're in and will try to load the correct environment. Older ones (pre 3.2?) would just run an arbitrary version of Rails.